# Mapbox kml lost accuracy

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Not sure if anyone has got this issue before but it seems mapbox has lost accuracy when importing points from KML. It is the same KMLs loaded on the left and right and the differences are really clear.

[image: The difference]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be mapbox cannot process large amount of polylines. When I split to 2 files it works great.